# Как сделать в AJAX представление по-умолчанию?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "page1.html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("#content").html(html);
      }
    });
  });

  $('#btn2').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "page2.html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("#content").html(html);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Какую страницу желаете открыть?</p>
<form>
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Страница 1">
  <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Страница 2">
</form>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Есть вот такой вот код, в котором есть две кнопки переключения. Если нажать на btn1 появится контент страницы 1, а если на btn2, то страница 2. Как сделать, чтобы страница 1 была ***уже по умолчанию***, еще до нажатия?

```
<h2><input type="radio" name="operation" value="Страница 1" checked> Страница 1 </h2>
<h2><input type="radio" name="operation" value="Страница 2"> Страница 2 </h2>
```

Нужно что-то вроде checked, как в этих HTML-ных строках

Comment: Есть сумасшедшая мысль: а что если перенести код страницы 1 в эту страницу? Ну или, хотя бы, перенести код загрузки из обработчика клика в обработчик события загрузки страницы?

Comment: не выйдет, тогда контент будет дублироваться....

Comment: С чего бы ему дублироваться, если вы его заменяете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно завести массив страниц, и загружать их по индексу нажатой кнопки.
Предварительно загружаете страницу с индексом 0.

```
<p>Какую страницу желаете открыть?</p>  
<div>  
    <input class="loadBtn" type="button" value="Страница 1">   
    <input class="loadBtn" type="button" value="Страница 2">  
</div>  
<div id="content"></div>  

<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    var tpls = ['page1.html', 'page2.html'];

    $('.loadBtn').click(function(){  
      loadContent($(this).index());
    });  
    loadContent(0);

    function loadContent(index) {
      if (!tpls[index]) return;
      $.ajax({  
        url: tpls[index],  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
          $("#content").html(html);  
        }  
      });  
    }

  });  
</script>
```

---

Также можно перенести список шаблонов непосредственно в атрибуты кнопки:

```
<p>Какую страницу желаете открыть?</p>  
<form>  
    <input class="loadBtn" data-tpl="page1.html" type="button" value="Страница 1">   
    <input class="loadBtn" data-tpl="page2.html" type="button" value="Страница 2">  
</form>  
<div id="content"></div>  

<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){  

    $('.loadBtn').click(function(){  
      loadContent($(this).data('tpl'));
    });  
    loadContent($('.loadBtn').get(0).data('tpl'));

    function loadContent(url) {
      $.ajax({  
        url: url,  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
          $("#content").html(html);  
        }  
      });  
    }

  });  
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!!)

Comment: загнать в массив - очень хорошее решение в моем случае!код компактный и мой вопрос решен

Answer (score 4):

В описанной ситуации использовать ajax нецелесообразно. Если вам уже при загрузке страницы необходимо отдать определённую html структуру, формируйте её сразу, на сервере.

Выражение **include** включает и выполняет указанный файл.([источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php))

```
<div id="content"> 
    <?php include 'page1.html';?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...

  $('#btn1').click();
});
```

Comment: не переходит даже на указанный контент

Answer (score 1):

```
;(function(){

 $('#btn1').trigger( "click" );

}());
```

Comment: не переходит даже на указанный контент